# Why can't I use protoc generate Python3 object which has an Any type field via --python3_out, only --python_out works

Tags: python-3.x, protobuf-3

I created a proto file RpcCmd.proto, and defined one field with type `google.protobuf.Any`, when I tried to generate a Python3 object file with cmd `protoc --python3_out=./gen RpcCmd.proto` it failed with error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-python3", line 36, in <module>
    compiler = Compiler(desc_map[file_name], top_level_elements)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/protobuf3/compiler/__init__.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.process_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/protobuf3/compiler/__init__.py", line 104, in process_message
    self.process_field(message.name, field, embedded)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/protobuf3/compiler/__init__.py", line 148, in process_field
    file_to_import = splitext(self.__tle_map[top_level_name])[0].replace('/', '.')
KeyError: 'google'
--python3_out: protoc-gen-python3: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

But, if I typed with cmd `protoc --python_out=. RpcCmd.proto` it succeeded

I also tried `--java_out` worked without any error.

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message RpcCmd {
    google.protobuf.Any message = 1;
    string randomKey = 2;
}
```

Is it possible to use type `Any` with `--python3_out`?